# How to extract the server Host/IP from the CORBA IOR & NamingContextExt? [Java]

Tags: java, corba

I've got a Client who needs to send a UDP packet to a server and the only reference he has to the Server is through the CORBA naming service (IOR). I know the IOR has the Server Information embedded but is there an easy way for me to extract it?

This is the code I have so far:

```
Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);
Object o = ncRef.resolve_str(Name);
```

After this Object o contains the IOR (if I do o.toString() it sure looks like a valid IOR), so from this what can I do to get the corresponding Servers IP/PORT so I can send it a UDP packet?

I know this sounds odd - why not just invoke the remote method, well this is for a school project and the professor recommended simply storing another table with all the sever information - but I am trying to be creative and since I was reading about the IOR I thought maybe I could do something with it ...

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will help, but here's the properties I use to access an IBM CORBA naming service, maybe you can try to fetch those properties from your object.

- org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort
- org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost

  export ORB_PROPERTY="-DORBNamingProvider=CosNaming -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=${ORB_PORT} -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=${ORB_HOST} -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.Debug.Output=/dev/null"